# Angular form with file

Tags: angular, forms

I am having problem with form and its instancing, submitting etc.

Here is html code for my form:

```
        <form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div>
                <input type="file" formControlName="document" change="onFileSelect($event)"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

ts code:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

uploadForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
        private studentsService: StudentsService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            document: ['']
        });
    }

onFileSelect(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        this.uploadForm.get('document').setValue(file);
    }
}

onSubmit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.uploadForm.get('document').value);
    this.studentsService.uploadDocument(formData).subscribe(res => {
        alert('Succesfully uploaded document!');
        this.rerender();
        this.show = !this.show;
    });
}
```

So, on initialization of component I get the two following errors:

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
ERROR TypeError: this.form is undefined
```

I am pretty stuck here, it seems to me that I'm passing instance in ngOnInit() but somehow it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: move ngOnInit code inside constructor or add *ngIf="uploadForm" to <form>

Answer (score 0):

I moved ngOnInit code to constructor, it looks like this now

```
constructor(
        private studentsService: StudentsService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) { 
        this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            document: ['']
        });
}

ngOnInit(): void {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" *ngIf="uploadForm">`

I put in an `ngIf` in the form tag. So that the `<form>` will only render if uploadForm is created.

Comment: tried that one, but nothing happens then, form stays blank, moving it to constructor worked for me